# perl push many array in one array

Tags: perl

I have many short array

```
 @seq1 /773..1447/        @seq2 /1 2 1843..1881 1923..2001/
```

but i use push

```
   push(@add, @seq1);
   push(@add, @seq2);
```

but it shows like it combine all array into one can't get each sub-array any more

```
  /773..1447 1 2 1843..1881 1923..2001/
```

when i use

```
  $number=@add;
```

it shows 6, but it should be 2. Can anyone explain the reason and how to change it.

When i use for loop to add each array

```
   for(..){
 @temp= split(/,/,$_); 
 push(@add, \@temp);
 }
```

Then when i print @add; it only shows memory address, How can show all data in @add

Comment: You really need to read [perldoc perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal behavior, use reference to `@seq1` if you want `@add` to be two dimensional array,

```
push(@add, \@seq1);
```

To print all values in `@add` you should `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@add;`

The reason is that all parameters get flattened into list when they are pushed into array, so

```
@a = @b = (1,2);
push(@add, @a, @b);
```

is same as writing

```
push(@add, $a[0],$a[1], $b[0],$b[1]);
```

Check [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

the `push` command takes an *ARRAY* and a *LIST*. It is important to understand what happens here.

The first argument **must be** an *ARRAY*, the one you want to push things on. After that it expects a *LIST*. What this means is that this `push` statement provides **list context** to any @seq_*n* array - and sort of expands the array into separate elements. So all the elements of the @seq_*n* are being pushed onto your @add.

Since you did not want that to happen, you wanted an array that holds the separate lists - what we call in Perl a List-of-Lists - you actually wanted to `push` a reference to your @seq_*n* arrays, using the `\` character.

```
push @add, \@seq_1, \@seq_2, . . . \@seq_n;
```

Now you have an array that indeed holds references to each $seq_*n*.

To print them neatly, each sequence on its own line, you could iterate over each

```
foreach my $seq (@add) {
  # $seq holds a reference to a list!
  my $string = join " ", @$seq; # the @ dereferences the $seq
  print $string, "\n";
}
```

but *TIMTOWTDI*

```
print map {(join " ", @$_), "\n"} @add;
```

Always consider the context in Perl, and try to embrace the charms of join, grep and map.